# Getting the list of fields that will be serialized by Jackson

Tags: java, json, reflection, jackson

I am trying to programmatically get the list of fields in a class that will be serialized while using Jackson serializer.

I can write code based on reflection to go over the fields in the class to see which ones are public, have getter/setter, or have Jackson specific annotations, etc. and come up with a list as per the rules followed by Jackson to decide whether a field will be serialized. But there is a good chance that the implementation will be incomplete.

Is there any way using the Jackson library that I can achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to find default bean serialiser using `findValueSerializer` and list all properties. See below example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;

public class JsonApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonSerializer<Object> serializer = mapper.getSerializerProviderInstance().findValueSerializer(Result.class);
        serializer.properties().forEachRemaining(p -> {
            System.out.println(p);
        });
    }
}

class Result {

    @JsonIgnore
    private int id = 1;
    private String name = "Jack";

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("id")
    public String getIdAsString() {
        return "ID:" + id;
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
property 'name' (via method com.celoxity.Result#getName, static serializer of type com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StringSerializer)
property 'id' (via method com.celoxity.Result#getIdAsString, static serializer of type com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StringSerializer)
```